# File-Monitoring via Lua Script

Tags: csv, lua, eventtrigger, file-monitoring

Good evening,

I am currently developing a way to import machine created data from a csv sheet into a database.
The question I have is, is there a way to react to a change in a csv file with Lua.

The file gets a line in this format:

`17162H,"801234500001",9/23/2016 12:33:30 PM,"INV"`

Every time a scanner is finishing a scan process, added under the old lines, but there is no direct connection to the database, to trigger the script.

It doesn't matter if the change is detected via different file size, foldersize (of the folder that contains the file) or a change within the file information (like date of last opening), but I can't open and read in it permanently due performance reasons.

Also this is the first time I ask here, so sorry for my clunky way, I'll try to improve myself with that over time.

Comment: What code have you got already and will the script work permanently or will it be started sometimes?

Comment: Some code would be helpful, as well as what platform are you using.

Comment: Do you really need this in real time? May be just poll it every N mins. Also it may be important to nknow how your apps rotate this log file.

Comment: Kulchenko's tip worked, thank you, Question can be closed (for some reason I can't do that)

Comment: @ismalith If his answers helped you, please accept it by hitting that shiny green checkmark. This helps future programmers with similar problems find their solution!

Comment: I am sorry, forgot to do that, marked it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run this on Windows, you can use [winapi library](https://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html), which supports [file watchers](https://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#watch_for_file_changes). Here is an [example](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/refreshproject.lua#L39-L43) of how it's used in one of my projects; you'll need to call `winapi.sleep()` to allow time for the check to trigger.

Comment: I test it few years ago. It some time crash after some work time. But i do not test it since then

Comment: I used watchers on Win8 and haven't seen any problems with it. I also have users that use it regularly and they haven't reported any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [linotify](https://github.com/hoelzro/linotify), it has lua bindings for inotify and looks like it should do the trick, using the "modify" event to trigger your script.

Answer (score 2):

I use LibUV based variant in my [spylog apllication](https://github.com/moteus/lua-spylog/blob/master/src/filter/lib/spylog/filemon.lua)
Usage:

```
file_monitor(path_to_file, {eol = '\r?\n'}, function(line)
  ... 
end)
```